# Downloading file through rest api spring boot and with multiple NULL

Tags: spring-boot, csv

I have a `rest controller` which is downloading a `CSV File` from classpath.

```
@GetMapping("/template/download")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> downloadCsv() throws IOException {
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.set( HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=template.csv" );
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).headers(httpHeaders).body(csvUtil.downloadCsvTemplate());
    }
```

Below is my `downloadCsvTemplate()` code

```
public byte[] downloadCsvTemplate() throws IOException {
        File resource = new ClassPathResource("templates/template.csv").getFile();
        return util.convertFileToByteArray(resource);
    }
```

```
public byte[] convertFileToByteArray(File file) throws IOException {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

        try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(bytes)) != -1;) {
                bos.write(bytes, 0, readNum);
            }
        }

        return bytes;
    }
```

When I try to hit the API I am able to download the file with content but I am getting some additional contents like below-

[image]

Any idea on how to get only the below content:

```
email,password,firstName
abc@abc.com,ABC@123,Test
```

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are seeing raw data in the response is that CSV is nothing but a comma-delimited string. Try to add content-type.

```
@GetMapping("/template/download")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> downloadCsv() throws IOException {
    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.set( HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=template.csv" );
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("text/csv")).headers(httpHeaders).body(csvUtil.downloadCsvTemplate());
}
```